# Method not found: 'Void RestSharp.RestClient.set_BaseUrl(System.String)'. in TWILIO

Tags: c#, asp.net, twilio

I created a webpage to make a phone call using Twilio.

[please refer the link](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/partner-twilio-cloud-services-dotnet-phone-call-web-role/#twilio-prereqs)

When I execute, it displays following error,

> Method not found: 'Void RestSharp.RestClient.set_BaseUrl(System.String)'.

I used same codes on that link.

please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: That code example you refer to is a couple years old so it most likely won't work with more recent Twilio packages, especially since newer ones removed the RestSharp dependency.

Answer (score 6):

Twilio evangelist and maintainer of the C# library here.

RestSharp, which the Twilio library uses, just released a new version that introduced a breaking change.  I'll be updating the C# library asap to fix this.

In the mean time you can work around this by first installing version 104.4 of RestSharp:

```
Install-Package RestSharp -Version 104.4
```

And then installing the Twilio helper library.

Hope that helps and sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: We are also using twilio with latest library and RestSharp -Version 105.0.1 but we are getting same error with MVC5. What can be issue here? Please advice me.

Comment: I'm having the same issue , I installed RestSharp 104.4 using your command above but the Twilio library has the dependency set to RestSharp 105> , so when I installed Twilio it updates my RestSharp library and it's giving me the error, any idea?